# Will different brushless motor sizes work with the same flight controller and esc

Tags: flight-controller, brushless-motors, esc

I recently built a 5-inch quad using:

- Diatone Mamba F405 Mk2 F40 Mk2 3-6S 30x30 Stack/Combo (F4 FC / 40A 4in1 ESC)
- Motors: iFlight Xing-E PRO 2207 1800Kv Motor with DShot 600 and 4S battery cell. I didn't notice any problems with the build when I did a test flight.

I am now trying to build a larger drone (850mm or 950mm X-Class). I was wondering if the same flight controller/esc combo would work for motors:
Cobra CM-2820/16 Multirotor Motor, Kv=740 ([link](https://www.cobramotorsusa.com/multirotor-2820-16.html))
and
iFlight XING X4214 400KV Motor ([link](https://shop.iflight-rc.com/xing-x4214-2-8s-x-class-fpv-nextgen-motor-pro802))

The cobra motor specifies that the pwm frequency is 8khz, but I didn't see any details on pwm frequency for the other brushless motors. So now I'm not sure whether pwm frequency is a parameter I need to consider when choosing an FC/ESC for a motor. Or is the 8khz a standard frequency that all FC/ESCs support? Usually I just make sure the ESC supports the maximum amp from the motor and propeller combination I plan to use, and that I have the correct LiPo battery cell count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be fine, brushless ESCs can normally run a very wide variety of brushless motors.

If they stutter or otherwise don't spin up reliably, you may need to adjust the timing settings in the ESC firmware. This controls when the motor winding are energised as they pass the magnets. Lower Kv motors can need a lower setting.

[Here's an article on BL Heli settings](https://oscarliang.com/best-blheli-32-settings/) (the ESC firmware)

Comment: Thank you Robin, timing was something I had not considered previously

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. The motor should not specify the PWM setting, that is something that comes from the ESC. You can effectively run a motor at any given PWM frequency, however the efficiency, torque, etc characteristics change.

The biggest concern with pairing a given ESC and motor is chosen voltage and current draw. 400kv seems a little low for 6S, but that's the max that ESC is rated for. If you wanted to run those motors on 8S, you'd need to get an ESC rated for that.

The 40A current rating is quite high, most ESCs are like this these days due to improved MOSFET technology. I highly doubt you'll load the motors enough to draw 40A, and the motor will likely die before the ESC does.

The FC/ESC interaction is another one, they need to speak the same language. With DSHOT, pretty much anything on the market will work together, so unless you're doing something weird, you don't need to worry much about this.

Comment: Thank you Brydon, I hadn't considered ESC voltage limitation, kv, and motor size. I think you had a nice explanation of the relationship here also: https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/236/why-do-higher-voltage-batteries-need-lower-kv-motors